# What is a minimum leaf spanning tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree, minimum-spanning-tree

Could someone explain to be what a minimum leaf spanning tree is? I am confused to what exactly is a leaf in a spanning tree. I understand a spanning tree contains simple paths with no cycles and it spans all vertices in a graph G, but what is a minimum leaf one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A leaf is a vertex of degree one in a tree. The degree of a vertex is equal to the number of edges that contain the vertex. A minimum leaf spanning tree is a problem that given a graph G = (V, E) and an integer i, is there a spanning tree T in G that contains at most i leaves?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a leaf here means a vertex with degree 1. So a minimum leaf spanning tree is a spanning tree with the minimum number of vertices with degree 1.